# Concrete nouns cannot be modified by abstract ones

Tags: nouns, terminology, modifiers, grammar-myths

> Concrete nouns cannot be modified by abstract ones.

I cannot understand this sentence. It does not mean that I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence, rather I cannot understand what it teaches.

Comment: Could you give us a source for this? As it stands it is simply wrong, so I suspect there is some narrow sense of "abstract" in play here.

Comment: [here is an example list of abstract nouns](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-abstract-nouns.html). I can most certainly put a lot of them in front of a concrete noun and have a meaningful collocation.

Comment: "Open your **grammar textbooks**, pupils, on page 27. We will dispell yet another grammar myth today".

Comment: Overexplanation of language that is absolutely unnessary.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence you mention claims that an abstract noun cannot be used as an *attributive noun*, modifying a concrete noun ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)).

The sentence likely implies that abstract nouns generally have a different form when used as adjectives. "Beauty" would become "beautiful", for instance.

There are, of course, exceptions. As mentioned by @CopperKettle, *grammar textbook* means a textbook about grammar. If one were to say *grammatical textbook* one would imply the textbook is written in grammatically correct English.